# How to fill table in sql server compact/sqllite?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I'm beginner to visual studio and I want to create local DB for c# project
so i installed sql server compact/sqllite for it
after installing it I created a new connection. Then build table
and then executed the table to see option of table I created under drop down menu "table"
I don't understand how to edit that table 
when I select edit top 200 rows I see the screen as in image
just one rows. I can't see 200 rows
and on top of that I can't even write in column
is there any special way to do it
or did I miss something that I should have done

[image]

Comment: You've created a table, but it's not clear whether you've populated it with any records. Insert a record by running an SQL statement and it should appear in the list subsequently.

Comment: To manage Sqlite I suggest to use Sqlite Professional, www.sqliteexpert.com/download.html, for starters it's easier. You can create, add tables, rows  and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Edit top 200 rows' means edit the data, not the table design (known as the table schema). If there's no data in the table—which if you just created it sounds like the case—you'll need to enter some before you can edit it.

You enter data in Visual Studio by clicking the cell that you want to edit.

Visual Studio 2015 no longer supports design tools for SQL Server CE, so you probably created a SQL Server `LocalDB` file instead (note no space in the word). That said, you can install Erik EJ's excellent SQL Server CE/SQLite ToolBox extension (more info [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/SQL-Server-Compact-and-SQLite-Toolbox)).